# Random "Alignment grids" on my monitor

Tags: display, external-display

I bought a new BenQ GW2480 monitor. When I quickly change images I get these random lines that look like "alignment grids"(in quotes because I don't know how to refer to them -- see image). For example, the Microsoft To Do app has these inbuilt wallpapers. When I quickly change between them (or change between different lists, which changes the wallpaper), I get these random lines that look like a grid.

[image]

Note that this problem is different from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234463/alignment-grid-suddenly-showed-up-on-my-desktop), [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-hide-the-alignment-grid/4e295fea-3eee-4009-b8f1-ec35a8af49db) or [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-have-random-grid-lines-across-the-computer/858acf79-1aac-4516-815f-b8dd330012f9?auth=1) in that this is completely random and goes away automatically if I change the screen. Further, they don't always appear on the same area. This one is just two lines -- sometimes I get a square or a grid at the bottom or top part alone (see second picture below). The other ones linked seem to be a permanent issue that is fixed when a particular monitor setting is changed. Also, in my case, the gridlines move when I move the window.
[image]

What's happening and how do I fix it? Some more info: I have an Acer Swift 3 laptop, Core-i5 8250U, Intel UHD 620 graphics and the monitor is a BenQ GW2480. ([Laptop](https://www.flipkart.com/acer-swift-3-core-i5-8th-gen-8-gb-256-gb-ssd-linux-sf314-52-laptop/p/itmf3s3gakhc4bwd?pid=COMF2YTDQQURXWJC&lid=LSTCOMF2YTDQQURXWJCFKNOAA) & [Monitor](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B073NTCT4Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1))

Comment: This isn't caused by the monitor. If it were, a screenshot would not capture the lines. Because it is in a screenshot the issue is caused by the computer. Have you checked for an installed the latest graphics drivers and software patches?

Comment: Yeah, I do have the latest drivers and software. This never happened with the integrated screen though.

Comment: Have you installed the [manufacturer's driver](https://www.benq.com/en-us/support/downloads-faq/products/monitor/gw2480/software-driver.html) (although being from 2018, it might not relate)?

Comment: Have you tried another HDMI cable ?

Comment: Yes, I've installed both the BenQ driver and the manufacturer Intel HD Graphics driver from Acer. I've also tried another HDMI cable.